# Thought Experiments on black holes, (im)possible perpetual motion and minimum mass for photographic plates

Tags: black-holes, perpetual-motion

Consider a black hole in vacuum at Temperature T. The setup that I am interested is a one that collects thermal photons from a black hole by enclosing in a spherical photographic plate and then lowering it back into the black hole.

If one assumes that photographic plates are massless.(which they are not). Then the very fact that I can lower the photographic plates(after the photons are collected) back into the black hole allows for a possibility of for the creation of a perpetual motion machine, from the potential energy generated by lowering the collected photons back into the black hole.

The mass of the photons emitted is equal to the mass of the black hole that has evaporated away. When I drop the photons back in the black hole, The mass of the black hole is equal to the original mass that we started off with. Which is why i thought it could be perpetual. This can continue for ever.

Of course I know something is wrong with such a setup. I think It can be traced to my assumption about photographic being massless.

My understanding of black hole thermodynamics is pretty elementary. Perhaps some one could comment on what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hawking radiation emitted from the Black Hole lowers its mass and reduces the energy in it's gravitational field. If you now drop the photographic plate back into the Black Hole you will get energy back. However if you take that energy away, by using it to generate electricity or whatever, you leave the Black Hole with a lower mass. That's where the energy has come from.

Suppose you take a small enough Black Hole that it radiates a lot of energy and put it in the boiler of a steam engine. You can now use the heat to generate electricity, but of course the Black Hole eventually evaporates away to nothing. Take the same Black Hole and put it inside a perfect mirror, that reflects back all the emitted radiation, and the Black Hole remains unchanged but of course now you can't generate any electricity from it.

Comment: The mass of the emitted photons is equal to the mass of the black hole that has evaporated away. After I dropping the photons back in the black hole, The mass of the black hole is equal to the original mass that we started off with. Which is why i thought it could be perpetual.

Comment: @Prathyush: the photons redshift on their way from the black hole to the plate.  The energy lost to the redshifting equals the energy gained from the lowering of the plate.  Also, photons have no mass--their energy equals their momentum.

Comment: @Jerry: I am using mass as Energy in a synonymous manner. If you drop an object mass m into a black hole, and you wait for it to evaporate away. The Total Mass(energy) of the photons you collect at far off from the horizon will be equal to the mass of the object you threw in Is it not? So redshift should not count.

Comment: @Prathyush: nope--the redshift is precisely a loss of energy, analogous to the slowing down of a massive particle as it rises in a gravitational field.  There is no conserved mass of a photon.

Comment: @Jerry: I know what redshift is. If a photon is absorbed by a photographic plate there will be an increase in the mass of the photographic plate. The Increase in the mass of the photographic plate is equal to energy of the photon absorbed.(In this sense I use energy and mass as equivalent). When the black hole radiates away its mass as photons, the energy radiated through photons(as seen from a distant observer) will be equal to change in the mass of the black hole. Which is why I say redshift of the photons will not explain this at all.

Comment: @Prathyush: the screen will appear to be redshifted relative to conformal infinity.  And it will also appear to be redshifted relative to the horizon.  If you let the photons go all the way to conformal infinity (at least close enough to be undetectable), then you will simply re-add the mass decrease of the black hole into the black hole.  No net energy loss or gain.  There is no paradox or perpetual motion here.

Comment: @Jerry: I din't quite follow, when you say "the screen will appear red shifted." If you agree that the increase in the in the mass of the photographic plate is equal to loss of mass of the black hole. Then you can convert the potential energy into work.

Comment: @Prathyush: sure (provided that it doesn't violate the second law).  And once you've done that work, you've used it, and can't lower the stuff back into the black hole and put it back there.  That isn't perpetual motion, it's finding a process for extracting energy and using it.

Comment: @John Rennie: you say that "However if you take that energy away, by using it to generate electricity or whatever, you leave the Black Hole with a lower mass. That's where the energy has come from." can you elaborate?

Comment: If a black hole emits some quantity of Hawking radiation then recaptures it, the black hole mass remains unchanged. However suppose we trap the radiation, maybe with a photographic plate, then the radiation doesn't return to the black hole. We, that is the region outside the black hole, now have more energy than we started with and that energy has to come from somewhere. It comes from the black hole mass i.e. the black hole mass (as mesured by us) has decreased by $E/c^2$, where $E$ is the amount of energy we have captured.